# Get data out of html table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, cell

I have a huge html table that I am building dynamically, and I want to be able to get cell data out of it easily.
Here is how my table is set up.

```
   <tr><td  id="presCode0">V</td></tr>
    <tr><td  id="presCode1">F</td></tr>
```

Each row element is numbered when I build my table.
Each row has 5 cells and there are hundreds of rows in the table.  Each row when clicked calls a function like this:

```
onclick="switchToRequest(rownumber)"
```

I have tried using:

```
function switchToRequest(i)
{
var presCode=''+'presCode' + i + '';
attend.elements["codePick"].value=presCode.innerHTML;
attend.elements["codePick"].value=$("#"+"presCode"+i);
}
```

is there any way that I can get table cell values out of a complex table using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
attend.elements["codePick"].value = $("#"+"presCode"+i).html();
```

or

```
attend.elements["codePick"].value = $("#"+"presCode"+i).text(); // to get text minus html tags
```

Comment: i got an error "cannot call method ' getElementsByTagName' of null"  myTable is the name of the table i want to get stuff out of right.  now the id?

Comment: awesome.  i used .text() and it worked great! thanks.  i thought jquery would have the answer but i wasn't sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
presCode.innerHTML;
```

with

```
$("#"+presCode).innerHTML;
```

and remove the second attend.elements line

Comment: when i do that i get the error "object presCode0 has no method 'innerHTML"

Comment: try .text() instead of .innerHTML

Comment: Removed my -1. If `$` is jQuery, then it still isn't right, but OP hasn't told us what `$` means in his code.

Comment: $ is jQuery.  sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 0):

```
function switchToRequest(i)
{
var presCode=''+'presCode' + i + '';
attend.elements["codePick"].value=document.getElementById(presCode).innerHTML;
attend.elements["codePick"].value=$("#"+"presCode"+i);
}
```